# Is this question about theme song lyrics on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Please have a  look at this question: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/10615/what-are-the-lyrics-to-the-title-song-for-the-tv-show-they-came-from-outer-spac

Basically it asks for the full lyrics of the theme song of an old scifi tv show.

What I don't like about it:

- It is a rather clear case of trivia knowledge.
- It is not really a question about the show, but about the music in the show...
- ...which would be ok, if the answer to it added any kind of deeper insight into the show's understanding, interpretation or nontrivial background knowledge, which it doesn't.

What one could hold in favor of the question:

- It (once) was an actual problem the person asking faced.
- It's trivia about the show that is supposedly hard to find.

In the comments JoshDM makes a connection to [another question about a theme song](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/10346/what-accounts-for-the-variation-in-the-gilligans-island-theme-song-between-seas), which in my eyes doesn't really hold because the other one actually uncoveres some facts about the shows history instead of being blunt trivia.

I think the question is too superficial to fit into the site's scope, but maybe I am wrong.

What are your thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2):

Here's my opinion on it.  Asking for the lyrics to the theme song is a trivia question.  Sure, you might appreciate having the lyrics to read while the song's playing, but knowing the lyrics doesn't futher your appreciation of the show, just the song.

Answer (score -1):

Had I never asked the original question a few years ago as I had, and held onto it till now, I would never have had the answer, since the original forum I asked it on cleaned house.

Movies and TV has the "*identify a show/film*" tag; what if all one had to go on was a theme song?

What if the question was, ***"What's the show where the theme song was {whatever}"*** and in the question was the full theme song, but no show information?

And then as an answer, I provide **the name of the show and some minor show details.**

According to the FAQ identification rules, **that qualifies as a viable question**, but according to you, the tougher-to-answer reverse of that question doesn't qualify?

To me, that is nonsensical.

As noted in the question, I'm not looking for upvotes (my focus is on StackOverflow itself for reputation); I'm looking for placing a record of this information somewhere more stable than a forum that got wiped out (the original place I asked my question).

Comment: The problem is that, in the one direction it's a tv id question, which is on-topic for this site.  The flip side is a music id question, which is off-topic for this site.  The only other lyric identification question we have is a special case where the show made changes to the song. http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/5649/what-are-the-chanting-lyrics-in-song-of-freedom

Comment: Also, your argument about the reverse being true is somewhat fallible.  One wouldn't post code on SO and ask for someone that has a problem that is fixed by that code.

Comment: That's correct about Stack Overflow, but if someone came here and said, "What's the name of the show where they end the title sequence with the words You're gonna make it after alllllll", you're not going to mark it off topic; you're going to post "Mary Tyler Moore" and call it a day.

Comment: Also, it's not a music id question.  I could go to dozens of music-related places and ask, but since it's tied specifically to a TV show and only used as the song for a TV show, no music afficionado is going to know it.  TV people would recognize it; I'd get told by a Music SE site to ask it here instead.

Comment: @JoshDM And again the argument that the people here are likely to be able to answer this easily. Sorry, but that's just completely irrelevant.